# Efficient code for solve this equation

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

We have $a*b*c=-1$, $\frac{a^2}{c}+\frac{b}{c^2}=1$, $a^2 b+a c^2+b^2 c=t$

What's the value of $a^5 c+a b^5+b c^5$?

I tried

```
Eliminate[{a b c == -1, a^2/c + b/c^2 == 1, a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a == t, 
  a b^5 + b c^5 + c a^5 == res}, {a, b, c}]
```

It's much slower than Maple's eliminate.  How do I solve this efficiently?

Comment: You can try to solve first and then evaluate?  

    sol = Solve[{a b c == -1, a^2/c + b/c^2 == 1, 
   a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a == t}, {a, b, c}]  
    Evaluate[a b^5 + b c^5 + c a^5 /. sol[[1]]]

I am not sure if this is the type of result you are looking for.

Comment: @BarisV Thansks. I tried this, but to simplify it is so slow.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use the third argument in `Solve`, i.e. a list of variables to be eliminated (take a look at the [Eliminating Variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EliminatingVariables.html) tutorial in `Mathematica`) then you'll get the result immediately :

```
Solve[{a b c == -1, a^2/c + b/c^2 == 1, 
       a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a == t,
       a b^5 + b c^5 + c a^5 == res},
      {res}, {a, b, c, t}]
```

> ```
> {{res -> 3}}
> ```

**Edit**

It should be underlined that `Solve` appears to be smarter than `Eliminate` due to its improvement in `Mathematica 8`, look at its options, e.g. `MaxExtraConditions`, `Method` ( `Method -> Reduce`). However most of the update of `Solve` is hidden, but in general it shares its methods with `Reduce`. Defining

```
system = { a b c == -1,
           a^2/c + b/c^2 == 1, 
           a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a == t,
           a b^5 + b c^5 + c a^5 == res };
```

then it works too

```
Solve[ system, {res}, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{res -> 3}}
> ```

while it doesn't in `Mathematica 7` yielding

> ```
> No more memory available.
> Mathematica kernel has shut down.
> Try quitting other applications and then retry.
> ```

and your original problem should be evaluated this way (you've lost `t`):

```
Eliminate[ system, {a, b, c, t}]
```

> ```
> res == 3
> ```

and it works in `Mathematica 7` as well.

Answer (score 7):

Can compute a Groebner basis with an ordering that eliminates `{a,b,c}`.

```
eqns = {a b c == -1, a^2/c + b/c^2 == 1, a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a == t, 
   a b^5 + b c^5 + c a^5 == res};
GroebnerBasis[
 Numerator[Together[Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}]]], {res, t}, {a, b, c}]

(* Out[150]= {-3 + res} *)
```

The result is now immediate.

Answer (score 3):

I found two methods:

```
Reduce[{a b c == -1, a^2/c + b/c^2 == 1, a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a == t, 
   a b^5 + b c^5 + c a^5 == res}, {t}] // First
(*res == 3*)

res /. Solve[{a b c == -1, a^2 + b/c == c, a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a == t,
     a b^5 + b c^5 + c a^5 == res}, {a, b, c, res}] // Union
(*{3}*)
```

Comment: In general, this way is recommended : `res /. {ToRules @ 
Reduce[{a b c == -1, a^2/c + b/c^2 == 1, 
     a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a == t, a b^5 + b c^5 + c a^5 == res}, {t}]}`. We can observe that we do not need this equation : `a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a == t`, i.e. we can get the solution this way `res /. {ToRules @ Reduce[{a b c == -1, a^2/c + b/c^2 == 1, a b^5 + b c^5 + c a^5 == res}, {res}]}`.

Comment: You can do also this `Normal @ Solve[{a b c == -1, a^2/c + b/c^2 == 1, a b^5 + b c^5 + c a^5 == res}, {res}, MaxExtraConditions -> All] `

Comment: @Artes Thansk you very much.