# Eliminate 3 Variable from 4 Equations

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to use *Mathematica* to `Eliminate` 3 following variable from 4 equations. Any clue or link to similar solved problem is highly appreciated:

```
eq = {
  Cos[θ] + Cos[ϕ] + Cos[ψ] == a,
  Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ] + Sin[ψ] == b,
  Cos[2 θ] + Cos[2 ϕ] + Cos[2 ψ] == c,
  Sin[2 θ] + Sin[2 ϕ] + Sin[2 ψ] == d};
Eliminate[eq, {θ, ϕ, ψ}]
```

Comment: If you get rid of the double angles first, it works fine.  Try `eq = TrigExpand @ {...`

Comment: Very nice n simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Solve` can eliminate variables too, e.g. `Solve[eq, {a, b, c, d}, {θ, ϕ, ψ}, 
 InverseFunctions -> True]` it is even smarter than `Eliminate` (read carefully [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21042/efficient-code-for-solve-this-equation/21043#21043)). [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42121/how-to-substitute-the-following-conditions-into-an-expression/42122#42122) can be helpful as well.

Comment: @wxffles Why not post an answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Because I'm lazy and I already have more internet points than I can spend.  But I found something interesting about the answer.  Behold!

Comment: @Artes I propose that you post your answer as well. I think that it is of value, if one can solve the same problem using different approaches. Then in a more complex problem, in which one of these approaches will fail, the other may work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Removing the double angles (e.g. $\cos(2 \theta) = \cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)$) with `TrigExpand` allows the elimination to be performed:

```
eq = TrigExpand @ {
  Cos[θ] + Cos[ϕ] + Cos[ψ] == a,
  Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ] + Sin[ψ] == b,
  Cos[2 θ] + Cos[2 ϕ] + Cos[2 ψ] == c,
  Sin[2 θ] + Sin[2 ϕ] + Sin[2 ψ] == d};
Eliminate[eq, {θ, ϕ, ψ}]
```

> $a^4+2 a^2 \left(b^2-c-2\right)+\left(b^2+c\right)^2+d^2=4 b (a d+b)$

Let us plot this implicit surface:

```
ListAnimate @ Table[ContourPlot3D[
  a^4 + 2 a^2 (-2 + b^2 - c) + (b^2 + c)^2 + d^2 == 4 b (b + a d),
  {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 5}], {d, -5, 5, 0.2}]
```

[image: pipepass]

Comment: Simply amazing. Thanks for enlightening clues and animation.