# How to eliminate the list case by `Eliminate` function

Tags: equation-solving

It is known that line L1: $\frac{x-a_{2}}{a_{1}}=\frac{y-b_{2}}{b_{1}}=\frac{z-c_{2}}{c_{1}}$ and line L2: $\frac{x-a_{3}}{a_{2}}=\frac{y-b_{3}}{b_{2}}=\frac{z-c_{3}}{c_{2}}$ intersect at a point.

Now I want to find the possible relationship between vectors $a_{1}=\left[\begin{array}{l}
a_{1} \\
b_{1} \\
c_{1}
\end{array}\right]$, $a_{2}=\left[\begin{array}{l}
a_{2} \\
b_{2} \\
c_{2}
\end{array}\right]$, $a_{3}=\left[\begin{array}{l}
a_{3} \\
b_{3} \\
c_{3}
\end{array}\right]$.

But I had trouble solving this problem with the following code:

```
Eliminate[(x0 - a2)/a1 == (y0 - b2)/b1 == (z0 - c2)/c1 && (x0 - a3)/
     a2 == (y0 - b3)/b2 == (z0 - c3)/c2 && α1 = {a1, a2, 
    a3} && α1 == {a1, a2, a3} && α2 == {b1, b2, 
     b3} && α3 == {c1, c2, c3}, {x0, y0, z0}](*Suppose that the intersection of two lines is {x0, y0, z0}*)
```

Even I can't get the relationship between vectors with specific values:

```
Solve[α1 == {1, 2, 3} && α2 == {1, 0, 
    0} && α3 == {2, 2, 3} && α3 == 
   k1*α1 + k2*α2, {k1, 
  k2}, {α1, α2, α3}]
   
 Reduce[α1 == {1, 2, 3} && α2 == {1, 0, 
        0} && α3 == {2, 2, 3}, {α1, α2, α3}](*we should get a result like α3 == α2 + α1*)
```

`Eliminate` function seems to be unable to directly deal with the relationship in the form of vector, what should I do to better solve this problem?

Comment: Introducing  `α1, α2, α3 ` is superfluous. This should satisfy your expectations: `Eliminate[(x0 - a2)/a1 == (y0 - b2)/b1 == (z0 - c2)/c1 && (x0 - a3)/
    a2 == (y0 - b3)/b2 == (z0 - c3)/c2, {x0, y0, z0}]`.

Comment: @Artes Thank you for your reply, but the question requires to calculate the relationship between the three vectors. This is not the final result.

Comment: `Eliminate` in my comment provides a relation that you can transform as you like. Nevertheless there is also usage of `Solve` which eliminates appropriate variables e,g, `Solve[(x0 - a2)/a1 == (y0 - b2)/b1 == (z0 - c2)/c1 && (x0 - a3)/
    a2 == (y0 - b3)/b2 == (z0 - c3)/c2, {a3, b3, c3}, {x0, y0, z0}, MaxExtraConditions -> All]`, see e.g.these answers [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26147/am-i-missing-anything-solving-equations/26148#26148) and [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21042/efficient-code-for-solve-this-equation/21043#21043).

Comment: The answers which I linked are quite sufficient to get appropriate solution, nontheless neither `Eliminate` nor `Solve` provide equation in the form you expect. However if you find result you want to get you could also transform it to the form you expect, e.g. using `ReplaceAll` i.e. `/.`.